# Determine which region of the window is clicked

Tags: math, mouseevent

This is really sort of a general programming question.
I have a window split into 9 even squares.  When the user clicks one of those squares, I'd like to know which one.  I can get the location of the click via x and y variables.

My current approach is `xRegion = screenWidth / x` and `yRegion = screenHeight / y`  which will give me, for instance, (1,1) for the point (320,240) in a 640x480 window.  But that only works for `x` and `y` values greater than one third or so of the screen.  I know this is probably really simple, but I can't seem to wrap my brain around it.

Answer (score 2):

```
xRegion = (x*3) / screenWidth;
yRegion = (y*3) / screenHeight;

+-----+-----+-----+
| 0,0 | 1,0 | 2,0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 0,1 | 1,1 | 2,1 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 0,2 | 1,2 | 2,2 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

If you are ausing a language like js or php, you must floor/trunc the result to get an integer.
Add 1 to the results if you want the first region to be (1,1)

For results 1 to 9 do this: `cell = yRegion*3 + xRegion + 1;`

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Now I just gotta translate this into it's position on a 1D array...

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still trying to figure out why this works. :/